# MergeSort Implementation

Tags: sorting

I am having trouble getting the correct sorted list. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
merge_sort = function(list)
{
    #split list in half
    #sort each half
    #merge each half
    if(length(list<2))
        result = list
    else
    {
        middle = ceiling(length(list)/2)
        left = list[1:middle]
        right = list[middle+1:length(list)]
        merge_sort(left)
        merge_sort(right)
        while(min(length(left),length(right)) >0)
        {
            if(left[1] < right[1])
            {
                result = c(result,left[1])
                if(min(length(left),length(right)) >= 2)
                { 
                result = c(result,left[2:length(left)])
                result = c(result, right[2:length(right)])
                }
            }               
            else
            {
                result = c(result,right[1])
                if(min(length(left),length(right)) >= 2)
                { 
                result = c(result,right[2:length(right)])
                result = c(result, left[2:length(left)])
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return(result)
    print(result)
}
```

Comment: I get the original list as the output. Meaning if I input 4,3,2,1 I get 4,3,2,1 as the output. This is R code btw. But does the algorithm look correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you should use  `right = list[middle:length(list)]` instead of `right = list[middle+1:length(list)]`.